# MUI TablePagination adding ability to select page number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, pagination

I am using MUI TablePagination to create pagination in my table. The code is working fine and I'm getting most of the functionality I'm looking for:

1. The ability for users to select, via a dropdown, 5, 10 or 20 users per given page.
2. Dynamically display the number of pages based on the selected number of users per page.

However, I'm missing this functionality and I'm not sure what prop to use with this component to accomplish this:

3. The ability for users to navigate to a selected page from the listed number of result pages.

As you can see in [image: current table pagination] it displays 1-5 of 22, but I want to give users the ability to select page like in this [image: page selection pagination]

Here is my functional code:

```
<TablePagination
          rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 20]}
          component="div"
          count={showUser.length}
          rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
          page={page}
          onPageChange={handleChangePage}
          onRowsPerPageChange={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
/>
```

I want to accomplish this without removing 1,2 functionality.

Comment: I don't think that's possible with the TablePagination component.
It is possible with the Pagination component.
Perhaps you can manage the page size separate to the Pagination component and use Pagination component instead of TablePagination?
https://mui.com/material-ui/react-pagination/#basic-pagination .

i.e have a control with page size options that changes the bound table data based on the selection

Comment: Can you help me out with this? I can get Pagination working but not sure how to add the page size portion.

Comment: Sure, I'll put some sample code in an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, my suggestion would be to use the `Pagination` component instead of the `TablePagination` component.

This requires you to handle page sizes yourself.

This should help you get there, adapt it to your needs:

```js
const Demo = () => {
  const data = [
    "one",
    "two",
    "three",
    "four",
    "five",
    "six",
    "seven",
    "eight",
    "nine",
    "ten",
  ];

  const [pageSize, setPageSize] = useState(2);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

  const handlePage = (page) => setPage(page);

  const handlePageSizeChange = (event) => {
    setPageSize(event.target.value);
  };

  const totalPages = Math.ceil(data.length / pageSize);

  const pageContent = data.slice((page - 1) * pageSize, page * pageSize);

  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        {pageContent.map((item) => (
          <li>{item}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <select name="page-size" id="page-size" onChange={handlePageSizeChange}>
        <option value={2}>2</option>
        <option value={4}>4</option>
        <option value={6}>6</option>
        <option value={8}>8</option>
        <option value={10}>10</option>
      </select>
      <Pagination
        color="primary"
        count={totalPages}
        onChange={(event, value) => handlePage(value)}
        page={page}
        size="large"
      ></Pagination>
    </>
  );
};

export default Demo;
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I was able to adapt this to my needs. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TablePagination` instead of just the `Pagination` component. further, you can customize your pagination UI component by using `ActionsComponent` prop. https://mui.com/material-ui/api/table-pagination/ . Here I will post a sample example to replace pagination with the dropdown list.

```
<TablePagination
  rowsPerPageOptions={[10, 20, 50]}
  count={1000}
  rowsPerPage={10}
  page={pageNo}
  onPageChange={handlePageChange}
  ActionsComponent={(subProps: any) => {
    const {
      page,
      count,
      rowsPerPage,
      backIconButtonProps,
      nextIconButtonProps,
      showLastButton,
      getItemAriaLabel,
      showFirstButton,
      onPageChange,
      ...restSubProps
    } = subProps;
    return (
      <>
        <Select
          size="small"
          onChange={(e: any) => handlePageChange(e, e.target.value)}
          value={pageNo}
          MenuProps={{
            PaperProps: { sx: { maxHeight: 360 } }
          }}
          >
          <MenuItem id={1} key={1} value={1}>{1}</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem id={2} key={2} value={2}>{2}</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem id={3} key={3} value={3}>{3}</MenuItem>
         </Select>
      </>
    );
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Table Pagination still didn't provided direct to go page functionality . We need to customize our own pagination. I implement above one already . Its working but didn't provide direct go to page functionality